# Why do $\sum na_n x^{n-1}$ and $\sum na_n x^n$ have the same radius of convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Why is it that  $\sum na_n x^{n-1}$ and $\sum na_n x^n$ have the same radius of convergence $R$?

How can I show that 
$$\lim \sup|na_n|^{1/n} = \lim \sup |na_n x|^{1/n}$$ since this would mean that both series have the same radius of convergence $R$?

Comment: You can directly note they have the same radius of converge because one is just x times the other

Comment: That is exactly what I want to prove

Comment: can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using any formula for radius of convergence simply use the fact that $\sum na_nx^{n-1}$ converges iff $\sum na_nx^n$ does, for any $x \neq 0$. Obviously, this implies that they have the same radius of convergence.

Comment: But proving that part that one converges iff the other one does is what I don't get.

Comment: If $\sum a_n $ converges then $\sum c a_n$ also converges for any constant $c$. Apply this with $c=x$ in one direction and $c =\frac 1 x$ in the other direction.